# Toast messages in React - how to simply add a message to the Toaster?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement the Toast messages component. I have seen a few tutorials on that, but I don't quite understand how they add messages to the Toaster. I know how to do it with Redux or Context API, but is it possible without any of them? Most of these tutorials don't use them.

In my Toaster.jsx, I could do:

```
const Toaster = () => {
    const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([]);

    return (
        <ul>
            {toasts.map(({ id, message }) => (
                <Toast
                    key={id}
                    message={message}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default Toaster;
```

And then in some other component, I'd like to simply add toasts like this:

```
<button onClick={() => toast('Hello, world!')}>
    Display toast
</button>
```

What are the possible ways to communicate with the Toaster to make it add a message to its list of messages? Is it possible without wrapping any extra component on my App?

Comment: This is basic state management essentially. Keep a list of active toasts in state high enough in your app, pass it to your toasts list as prop and add to it at any point from elsewhere. Relevant doc section: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @ChrisG what does it mean in practice? Sounds like Redux/Context.

Comment: Without Context you have to pass the prop / adder function down the tree.

Comment: Can't it be achieved via custom hook or something else?

Comment: Without prop drilling or state management, I am not sure. One thing you can do without using all these, you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt). For triggering the states . Basically create your own `dispatchEvent`

Comment: You can use a custom hook, yes: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cdn-g05cv?file=/src/Toasts.js

Comment: @ChrisG I tested it and it looks like it only works when `addToast` and `<Toaster />` are in the same component. Is this the case, or am I missing something? Because toasts don't make much sense if they can't be used in children components, right?

Comment: @ChrisG that would make sense, since the docs says: "Do two components using the same Hook share state? No. Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated."

Comment: You can just not use state but a "global" array instead. Not sure why you don't just use Context, which exists precisely for situations like this.

Comment: @ChrisG I was thinking if it can be achieved in an easier way somehow. I'm normally using Context for these purposes, but I was surprised that these tutorials don't. But I think they just did it like you, so it only worked when everything is in the same component.

Comment: Can you link us to these tutorials?